# How to run Meteor on Android Emulator or devices?

Tags: android, meteor

When I try to run my Meteor app on Android devices, it gives me the error below:

```
Error detecting IP address for mobile app to connect to:
Found multiple network interfaces with non-internal IPv4 addresses:
10.0.2.182, 192.168.34.1, 192.168.224.1
Please specify the address that the mobile app should connect
to with --mobile-server.
```

Please someone, help me. How to run Meteor on Android emulator or devices?

Comment: to Cordova project:
   Cordova error: Failed to fetch plugin
   https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp.git via git.
   Either there is a connection problems, or plugin spec is incorrect:
   Error: "git" command line tool is not installed: make sure it is
   accessible on your PATH.
   (If the error message contains suggestions for a fix, note that this
   may not apply to the Meteor integration. You can try running again with
   the --verbose option to help diagnose the issue.)
ExitWithCode:1